# Displaying verbatim content with \tl_to_str:*

Tags: verbatim, expl3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{document}
\tl_to_str:n { testing _ things }

\par

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { testing _ things }
\tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl
\end{document}
```

gives a strange result (`testing ̇things`).  How can I get `testing_things`?  I basically want verbatim content (with line breaking).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `expl3`, but with the fact that OT1 encoded fonts don't have `_` in the ASCII slot for it (and miss several other characters). Do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. However, `\tl_to_str:n` will always add a space after control sequence names (when made of letters) and double `#`.

Comment: If you just want to grab verbatim, `\NewDocumentCommand\myverb{v}{\texttt{#1}}` will do it, with as @egreg says `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to deal with awkward chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by no means strange: if I try the simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A\char`\_B
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

because the standard fonts in OT1 encoding have the dot accent in the slot ASCII reserves for the underscore. Just adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

produces

[image]

because T1 encoded fonts have all the ASCII characters in their proper place.

The function `\tl_to_str:n` is not meant for verbatim, but for transforming input into a string consisting of category code 12 characters (spaces are still category code 10); it uses the same mechanism TeX uses for `\string`, in particular a space will be added after control words, so

```
\tl_to_str:n {\foo\baz?}
```

will print

> `\foo \baz ?`

Moreover, `#` characters will be doubled.

You can use it as a “poor person's verbatim”, if you're aware of these limitations:

```
\texttt{\tl_to_str:n{some_verbatim}}
```

will print

```
some_verbatim
```

also when the default encoding is OT1.